# How to make a pivot table in which the value of column will be obtained as an average for several days?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncw9d.png)

How to make a pivot table in which the value of column B will be obtained as an average for 3 days? In df2 it is shown what should happen.

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it2sN.png)

1 - 24/08/2021

2 - 25-27/08/2021

3 - 28-30/08/2021

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `set_index` with `resample` and `mean`:

```
df.set_index('A').resample('3d').mean()
```